# LNK1181 cannot open input file. space error?

Tags: c#, visual-c++, linker, visual-studio-2017, lib

I am having an compile error while trying to build my Windows Forms Project.

### My solution contains:

- 2 c# projects (one that creates a binary & one that is just a class with functions)
- 2 C++ projects (imported from another solution)

After import I had to re-reference the "Include Directorys" in the (project)Settings->VC++ Directories

These 2 solutions work but Im trying to have one solution instead of 2 ( them toghether. After import I had to re-reference the "Include Directorys" in the (project)Settings->VC++ Directories

And now I am getting this error:

Error: LNK1181 cannot open input file

"C:\SDK\Bin\x64 Release\\VS2017-PC.lib"

There are 3 problems with this link:

- It contains a double backslach
- It has a folder that is missing (C:\PC)
- There is the name "Release" instead of debug

The path should look like this:

'C:\PC\SDK\bin\x64 debug\VS2017-PC.lib'

I think it is because my folder "x64 debug" contains a space and is creating this error. But I dont know how to rename and refresh the paths correctly inside the solution and I dont even know if that would really fix this error.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4qxnn.jpg) of project Property Pages

Comment: I think something may be wrong with the path. Use escape characters. `C:\\SDK\Bin\\x64 Release\\VS2017-PC.lib`

Comment: @Gaurang Dave where do I specify the path to the Linker ?

Comment: Look in "project options/Linker/General/Additional library directories", and in "project options/Linker/Input/Additional dependencies".  Ideally  'Additional Library Directories' should contain something like "C:\PC\SDK\bin\$(PlatformTarget) $(Configuration)\" and the 'Additional Dependencies' just the lib name 'VS2017-PC.lib'.  Don't forget to check all platforms+configurations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to create the missing folder.
For some reason Visual studio didnt create "x64 debug" in the right directory.